# Angular2 - No provider for LoggedInGuard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-route-segment

I'm making a  Anuglar2 rc-4 web application. I'm trying to restrict routes but when i add my login guard, it tells me there is no provider. My normal login service code works fine, its just when i try to add the login guard and canActive routes. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

routes.ts

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { Home } from './components/home/home';
import { Login } from './components/login/login';
import { DashBoard } from './components/dashboard/dashboard';
import { User } from './components/user/user';
import { Store } from './components/store/store';
import { LoggedInGuard } from './models/logged-in.guard.ts'; 

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: Home, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: Login },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoard },
    { path: 'user', component: User },
    { path: 'store', component: Store },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

boot.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/common';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, JSONP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { App } from './components/app/app';
import { routes } from './routes';

bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    FormBuilder,
    provideRouter(routes)
]);
```

logged-in.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private ls: LoginService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.ls.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject your `LoggedInGuard` service inside your application bootstrap function

```
bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    FormBuilder,
    provideRouter(routes),
    LoggedInGuard // injected LoggedInGuard service provider here
]);
```

> **Note:** This answer would not be the same for the current angular 2 updated version(rc.6), When you upgrade you need to create a
>   `NgModule` where you are going to wrap up all the dependencies in
>   single place, that time `LoggedInGuard` will go inside `providers` option
>   of `NgModule

`

Comment: What's AuthGuard ?